# How to specify topology keys for kubernetes service declared with terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-cdk

I see that [since 1.17](https://kubernetes-docsy-staging.netlify.app/docs/concepts/services-networking/service-topology/) kubernetes has had alpha support for topology keys as a field on service definitions.

However, it seems that terraform does not allow specifying this key based on the docs found [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/service).

I'm specifically using [terraform cdk](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk) with typescript. How can I specify this key even though it's not yet officially supported by terraform?

I have the following

```js
import { Service } from "@cdktf/provider-kubernetes/lib/service";

export class MyConstruct extends Construct {


  constructor(scope: Construct, name: string, config: MyConstruct) {
    super(scope, name);

    const selector = {
      app: "my-app",
      name,
    };


    new Service(this, "my-service", {
      metadata: {
        labels: {
          app: "my-app",
          name,
        },
        name,
      },
      spec: {
        port: [
          {
            // stuff
          },
        ],
        selector,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

But when I try to add a `topologyKeys` field as a sister of the Servic spec, typescript complains that `Object literal may only specify known properties, and  topologyKeys  does not exist in type  ServiceSpec`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using old docs and the way to turn this on is by adding an annotation to the service as explained [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/topology-aware-routing/#enabling-topology-aware-routing)